# Why can't you generate a use case diagram from a state diagram?

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram, state-diagram

Why can't you, for example, take a state diagram, and make use case diagram based on this state diagram?

Comment: The same reason you can't "enhance" an image. The software can't invent information that isn't there.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.   The reason is simple:

- Use-cases are about actors.  Actors are outside the system, whereas the  state diagram is about the system.
- Use-cases should be about goals of the actors. You cannot infer intentions in the head of people from what happens in the system.  If I write a word CAPITALIZED, you cannot for sure tell if it is because my caps-lock is blocked,  because I want to draw your attention to something, or because I give another meaning to capitalized words.

Since most of the information related to use-cases are missing,  you cannot derive them from the state-diagram, except if you would have additional contextual information. Even then, it would be an educated guess, more than a rational, objective and repeatable process.